# How to add a div on click of a button in typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Currently, I am using angular 2.0. In one of my HTML files I have code like

```
<div class="row">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExtra">Add Extra      </button>
  </div>
```

How to add a div on click of this Add Extra Channel button.I need to have a div as mentioned below. Do I need add this HTML using typescript code?

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" id="title" style="width:100%" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You could use *ngFor on a div and bind that (on your .ts file) to an array where you'll push a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You would wire the `click` to a function that adds to a list in the controller. You would then use an `ngFor` (docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)` to loop through this list and add that template.

Answer (score 0):

If at all both of the Htmls are in the same page.In the typescript file declare the variable addExtra and set it as false by default.And on click of button make it true.

```
<div class="row">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExtra=true">Add Extra</button>
</div>

<div class="row" *ngIf="addExtra">
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <label for="title">Title</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
     <input type="text" id="title" style="width:100%" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to ad this section everytime I click on addExtra button. As many a times I click addExtra button those many times the div will get added. I think I cannot achieve it with this.